# Performing a function with 2 arguments with apply or aggregate

Tags: r, split, arguments, subset

I have data frames with several columns  used for splitting data (let's say 2 for now) in addition to "x" and "y" columns. I would like to perform function such as scatter plot or lm on "x" and "y" after subseting through the 2 columns.

I have been storing the "mini" data after each subset and calling further loops until I get the "x" and "y" I required, but it gets complicated after 3 or more loops. Recently, I tried to create a 'key' variable that stores all possible combinations.

Is there an easy way to split data first and call the function? perhaps an extension of apply or aggregate, but all factors to go through all combinations.

```
country <- rep(c("Australia","UK"), 2, each = 6)
gender <- rep(c("M","F"),1, each = 12)
X_height  <- rep(seq(150,200,10),4)
Y_weight  <- c(seq(70,95,5), 
               seq(71,96,5),
               seq(65,90,5),
               seq(66,91,5))



df <- data.frame(country, gender, X_height, Y_weight)

df[,"Key"] <- paste(df$country, df$gender, sep="_")

keys <- unique(df$Key)
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
sapply(1:length(keys), function(i){
  with(subset(df, Key == keys[i]),plot(x = X_height, Y_weight, main = keys[i]))
})
```

Thanks

Comment: it might be helpful to tag your question with the right language tag.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the aggregating function, `ave` or the packages `dplyr` or `data.table`.

If you are just plotting, you can use `ggplot2` with `facet_wrap`. Facet wrap takes a short formula based on what you want to group by:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = X_height, y = Y_weight)) +
       geom_line()  +
       facet_wrap(~country + gender, ncol = 2)
#the same as
ggplot(df, aes(x = X_height, y = Y_weight)) + 
       geom_line()  +
       facet_wrap(~Key, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Or with `facet_grid`: `ggplot(df, aes(x = X_height, y = Y_weight)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(gender ~ country)`

Comment: Thanks guys :) 'ave' seems like aggregate with mean as the default function. This is not what I am wanting to to. I am yet to learn dplyr and data.table. any particular functions in them you recommend? plotting is fine as well. I wish the solution was as easy as ggplot2! thanks again :)

Comment: If you want to learn, check out the cheat sheets: [dplyr](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) and [data.table](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf)